# Regex to find string not followed by another string before a character

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

Why doesn't this regex return true for this string: X1_Y1

`'.*X1_(?!(Y3|_))(_.*|$)'`

Since X1_ is not followed by Y3 before it hits either an underscore or the end of the string, the string X1_Y1 should be a match. What's wrong with my regex?

Comment: If you want `Y1` to match the second group, you need to change `_.*` to `.*` in the second group.

Comment: Blue's right remove underscore from 2nd capture

Comment: This will only work in the simple example I gave, but it will also return true for X1_Y1Y3_H5. This would be incorrect because I do not want this returning as true since there does exist a Y3 string in the string following X1 but before the next underscore.

Answer (score 0):

In the regex you gave, there is nothing which will match the `Y1` part. The `_` is already matched by the `X1_`, so the `_.*` part will not match, and the `$` won't match because there's still the `Y1` before the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Your expression can be simplified:

```
 .*X1_(?!(Y3|_))(_.*|$)
```

Is equivalent (for matching purposes and ignoring the capturing groups) to:

```
 X1_(?!Y3)(?!_)(_.*|$)
```

Since the negative lookahead disallows the character after `X1_`from being an underscore, this simplifies further to:

```
 X1_(?!Y3)(?!_)$
```

And since this expression requires `X1_` to end the string, the negative lookaheads serve no further function.  The expression simplifies to:

```
X1_$
```

Presumably, this is not what was intended.

Comment: To be clearer on the problem - I want to know there is an X1 which does not have a Y3 in the string following it, but before the next underscore. If I write it in English it would be: return true if the string contains X1_ following by a string NOT CONTAINING Y3 followed by either another underscore or the end of the string. I want the following to match: X2_T4R5R6_X1_Y1T1Y1_ as well as X4_U8Y8_X1_Y1 but not G6_H8H7H8_X1_Y7Y3Y9_. Also I want to return true if there is ANY X1 that does not have a Y3 following it, so this would also return true: X1_Y3Y7_X1_Y1Y2

Comment: @user2792676 What you may want then is something along the lines of `X1_(?![A-Z0-9]*Y3)[A-Z0-9]+`.  It matches if the input contains X1_ followed by a series of letters and numbers that does not contain `Y3`.

Comment: This works - thanks so much. Now that I see it, it seems so clear.